# Ajax Post form with conditions closing Tags

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need some help please.  I have a Ajax post form thats works great.  I decided to add a isNaN  to make sure numbers only in the Value. (else if).  Problem i am facing is that the script has stopped working because I am not closing the if statements correctly at the end of the script. My closing tags are wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#confirm-btn").click(function(event){
event.preventDefault(event);

var a = document.getElementById('bidamount').value;

//if bid amount is empty
if (a == "") {

//Change the text and color to red
document.getElementById('confirmtext').innerText  = "Input Amount";
document.getElementById("confirmtext").style.color = "red";
 
} else if {

var checkdata = document.getElementById('bidamount').value;
if(isNaN(data)){
 alert("it is not number");

} else {

//set var to bid number input field
var field1= $("#requestid").val();
var field2= $("#bidid").val();
var field3= $("#bidamount").val();

 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
     url: "scripts/sendbids_sql.php",
     data: {requestid:field1, bidid:field2, bidamount:field3 },
     success: function(data)
           {
            //Display AJAX Response 
           $("#ajax-response").show().html(data);
           //Hide thises fields from confirm section
           $("#confirm-btn").hide();
           $("#bidamount").hide();
           $("#confirmtext").hide();
           
           //Change Cancel button to OK
        document.getElementById('cancel-btn').innerText = "OK";
           

           }
   });
}

});
});
```

Comment: 2nd line from bottom needs to be }}); i think.

Comment: thanks I tried that but it  did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an if condition for you else if statement...

Am not going to guess at the actual functionality.. but the tags at the bottom are the proper closing tags for what you have here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#confirm-btn").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(event);

        var a = document.getElementById('bidamount').value;

        //if bid amount is empty
        if (a == "") {

            //Change the text and color to red
            document.getElementById('confirmtext').innerText = "Input Amount";
            document.getElementById("confirmtext").style.color = "red";

        } else if { //  <<----   Else if what?

            var checkdata = document.getElementById('bidamount').value;
            if(isNaN(data)) {
            alert("it is not number");

            } else {

                //set var to bid number input field
                var field1 = $("#requestid").val();
                var field2 = $("#bidid").val();
                var field3 = $("#bidamount").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "scripts/sendbids_sql.php",
                    data: { requestid: field1, bidid: field2, bidamount: field3 },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //Display AJAX Response 
                        $("#ajax-response").show().html(data);
                        //Hide thises fields from confirm section
                        $("#confirm-btn").hide();
                        $("#bidamount").hide();
                        $("#confirmtext").hide();

                        //Change Cancel button to OK
                        document.getElementById('cancel-btn').innerText = "OK";

// Correct closing tags
                    }
                });
            }

        };
    });
});
```

Comment: ohhh.. I see I am a complete Newbeeie...  I have IF twice!!   the else if  should be for the ... (isNaN(data)) {    THANKS!!!    :-)   Let me give it a try

Comment: SOLVED!  Thanks to DynasticSponge!!    Have a good evening